# Filter words and numbers in text file

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I want to make this text  :

```
203
00:16:38,731 --> 00:16:41,325
Happy Christmas.
your arse I pray God it's our last.
```

---

To be like this in variables :

```
Int section : 203
String start_time : 00:16:38,731
String end_time : 00:16:41,325
String Content :
Happy Christmas.
your arse I pray God it's our last.
```

---

In my search I found to use RegEx but I can't use it. That's i found it can help to understand what I mean :

```
Regex unit = new Regex( @"(?<sequence>\d+)\r\n(?<start>\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2},\d{3}) --\> " + @"(?<end>\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2},\d{3})\r\n(?<text>[\s\S]*?\r\n\r\n)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

This should work with subtitle files l
How can I do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try `var res = unit.Replace(s, "Int section : ${sequence}\nString start_time : ${start}\nString end_time : ${end}\nString Content :\n${text}");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication41
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "Int section : 203\n" +
                "String start_time : 00:16:38,731\n" +
                "String end_time : 00:16:41,325\n" +
                "String Content :\n" +
                "Happy Christmas.\n" +
                "your arse I pray God it's our last.\n";

            string pattern =
               @"Int section :\s+(?'section'\d+)\s+" +
               @"String start_time :\s+(?'start'[\d:,]+)\s+" +
               @"String end_time :\s+(?'end'[\d:,]+)\s+" +
               @"String Content :(?'content'[^$]+)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["section"].Value.Trim());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", match.Groups["start"].Value.Trim(), match.Groups["end"].Value.Trim());
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["content"].Value.Trim());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time .. but your input different of my ... i have subtitle file .. this work with on section of words .. and my text is must be like this :203
00:16:38,731 --> 00:16:41,325
Happy Christmas.
your arse I pray God it's our last.

Comment: It looks like there are spaces in the time so from : [\d:,] to : [\d\s:,]